# Oracle database creation - recording response file option not available

Tags: oracle-12c, installation

I try to create database with `dbca` assistant (v 12c) and I would like to firstly use the graphical guide in order to save the response file for later.

I checked the `advanced mode` during the step 2, I passed all the steps and then I went to the Summary step : I don't have the option "save response file" as you can see on my screenshot
[image: Summary]

I'm wondering if it's because this option is simply not available if we use `advanced mode` only ?

If you have any suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of the installer are you running?  Saving response files in DBCA is available starting with version 12.2.  You can maybe launch the installer using the -record option to create a response file:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b16227/oui4_response_files.htm#i1005622

Comment: Okay you're right, I've the response file version "12.1.0" 
I tried the -record option but it's saying that it's not an available option :)
Thanks